# SQL Server silently drops a transaction after a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions

SQL Server version 14.0.1000.169.

I start a transaction, execute a list of queries, but when I try to execute `commit`, I got an error `20018 The COMMIT TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION`.
There are no errors prior to it, and the connection is not breaking.

So I tried to log every DML query, executing `SELECT XACT_STATE(), @@TRANCOUNT` before and after each execution, here is what I got:

```
    [XACT_STATE()] => 0
    [@@TRANCOUNT] => 0
-----------------------
BEGIN TRAN
-----------------------
    [XACT_STATE()] => 1
    [@@TRANCOUNT] => 1
-----------------------
<<<Skipped several queries that do no cause the issue>>>
-----------------------
    [XACT_STATE()] => 1
    [@@TRANCOUNT] => 1
-----------------------
SELECT unpvt.productID AS ProductID,
       t.[Index] AS ImageSequence,
       unpvt.Image AS ImageFileName
INTO #tempImages
FROM (
         SELECT *
         FROM tProductNewImport pi
         WHERE pi.ProductNewImportInstanceID = :ProductNewImportInstanceID
           AND pi.deleted IS NULL
           AND pi.productID IS NOT NULL
           AND pi.StoreID = :StoreID
     ) pi
         UNPIVOT (Image FOR [Column] IN (f6)) unpvt
         JOIN (VALUES (1, 'f6')) t ([Index], [Column])
              ON t.[Column] = unpvt.[Column];

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NonClusteredIndex-c3975d93e8521] ON [dbo].[#tempImages]
(
    [ProductID] ASC,
    [ImageFileName] ASC
);



DELETE tpi FROM dbo.tProductImage tpi
JOIN #tempImages i on tpi.ProductID = i.ProductID
WHERE tpi.StoreID = :StoreID
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #tempImages i2 WHERE tpi.ProductID = i2.ProductID and tpi.ImageFileName = i2.ImageFileName);


UPDATE tpi
SET ImageSequence = i.ImageSequence * 10
FROM dbo.tProductImage tpi
JOIN #tempImages i on tpi.ProductID = i.ProductID and tpi.ImageFileName = i.ImageFileName
WHERE tpi.StoreID = :StoreID;


INSERT INTO tProductImage (StoreID, ProductID, ImageSequence, ImageFileName)
SELECT :StoreID, i.ProductID, i.ImageSequence * 10, i.ImageFileName
FROM #tempImages i
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.tProductImage tpi WHERE tpi.StoreID=:StoreID AND tpi.ProductID=i.ProductID AND tpi.ImageFileName=i.ImageFileName);
-----------------------
    [XACT_STATE()] => 0
    [@@TRANCOUNT] => 0
```

The last one is a single query with several statements in it.
The transaction disappeared after it, without any explicit 'end transaction' statements.
My only guess is that 'create index' command somehow performs a commit, but I could not found any information about that.

Comment: sql server does not silently drop transactions. you have a bug in your code....

Answer (score 1):

Use the following template instead:

```
SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT ON;

BEGIN TRY;
            
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    --

        /* your code goes here */

    --

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN;
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    END;

    THROW;

END CATCH;

SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT OFF;
```

The index creation is not affecting the [@@TRANCOUNT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trancount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) as:

> The BEGIN TRANSACTION statement increments @@TRANCOUNT by 1. ROLLBACK
> TRANSACTION decrements @@TRANCOUNT to 0, except for ROLLBACK
> TRANSACTION savepoint_name, which does not affect @@TRANCOUNT. COMMIT
> TRANSACTION or COMMIT WORK decrement @@TRANCOUNT by 1.

I am not sure how you are executing your code and why error is not returned. If you comment the `index creation` and the error is gone, maybe you have duplicated values and you are trying to create a unique index.

Use the template and let me know what's the result.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
As it turns out, the problematic query DOES raise an exception if you run it directly. For whatever reason it does not do this in the program, leaving it running it course, but without a session.